# Autolayout, programed vs interface builder

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, ios6, autolayout

Just to add a view that lives in the same parent view as the other two related views.

```
self.vDist = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 20, 42, 21)];
[self.vDist setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
[self.view addSubview:self.vDist];
NSLayoutConstraint *lc;
lc = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.vDist attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1.0 constant:20.0];
[self.view addConstraint:lc];
lc = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.vDist attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft multiplier:1.0 constant:20.0];
[self.view addConstraint:lc];
```

Then, I create the small squared view on top

```
/*********************** video view */
self.videoView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(90, 20, 140, 140)];
[self.videoView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
[self.videoView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
[self.view addSubview:self.videoView];

// width & height constraints, as UIViews don't have intrinsic constraints

lc = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.videoView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:nil attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute multiplier:1.0 constant:140.0];
[self.videoView addConstraint:lc];
lc = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.videoView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:nil attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute multiplier:1.0 constant:140.0];
[self.videoView addConstraint:lc];

// center constraint

lc = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.videoView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0];
[self.view addConstraint:lc];

// top constraint with its parent view

lc = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.videoView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1.0 constant:20.0];
[self.view addConstraint:lc];
```

This squared view shows ok in any device orientation

Now I create the second view on the lower part of the screen. It really doesn't matter its dimensions here as I create a constraint for each size attribute

```
/*********************** listado view */
self.listadoView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 248, 310, 100)];
[self.listadoView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
[self.listadoView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[self.view addSubview:self.listadoView];

// height and width constraints as UIView don't have intrinsic constraints

lc = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.listadoView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:nil attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute multiplier:1.0 constant:310];
[self.listadoView addConstraint:lc];
lc = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.listadoView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:nil attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute multiplier:1.0 constant:300];

// make it weak to be able to squeeze contents

lc.priority = 250;
[self.listadoView addConstraint:lc];

// top with videoView's bottom

lc = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.listadoView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationLessThanOrEqual toItem:self.videoView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom multiplier:1.0 constant:88.0];
[self.view addConstraint:lc];

// top with parent's view top

lc = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.listadoView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom multiplier:1.0 constant:248.0];
[self.view addConstraint:lc];

// center constraint

lc = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.listadoView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0];
[self.view addConstraint:lc];
```

trying to replicate here what IB did with the constraints in the other view

```
lc = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.listadoView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft multiplier:1.0 constant:5];
[self.view addConstraint:lc];
lc = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.listadoView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom multiplier:1.0 constant:10];
[self.view addConstraint:lc];
```

Te resulting screens are below with the green square. The vertical green screen shows what I was expecting (see yellow images down below), but in the green horizontal, as you can see, the bottom edge of the listadoView is below the edge of the screen, even though I'm setting all the constraints IB sets for the yellow one, those along with the ones I set in the yellow one too.

Any advice on how to set the constraints?... maybe the order in which they are created has something to do with it?, because there were times when I removed a constraint and it worked, then I re-added that constraint and still worked!. Ran it again with all the constraints, and then stopped working (what?!). And it's been hard to successfully reproduce it in order to file a bug, but it happened.

I've tested this code in XCode 4.6 under iOS5.1 and 6.x and with xCode 5 under iOS6.1.

[image: constraints settings in IB]
[image: yellow vertical]
[image: yellow horizontal]
[image: green vertical]
[image: green horizontal]

Answer (score 0):

Found my error. I was setting the listadoView's bottom constraint with its parent view to be 10, that is +10, and it should be -10. With this, the interface shows as with the other .xib (with the yellow square).